# can I add paramter to uri in kong api

Tags: kong

I want to add a paramter to the uri defined in kong...

example: http://localhost:8000/gam/v1/start/{topic}

is it possible to perform this with kong apis?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/Mashape/kong/issues/677#issuecomment-313798340 - I think that'll help once it is released in Kong.